# Do I have to give Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer Winter '17 Release Exam?

Tags: certification

I have not given Salesforce Certified Platform App Builder Transition Exam yet and I got a mail from salesforce saying I have to complete "Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer Winter '17 Release Exam" by 14th July, 2017.

But in mail it is also mentioned that "At this time you will not be able to renew your Force.com Developer credential as it will expire after July 31, 2017. Not to worry - even when your Force.com Developer credential expires, you will still have access to the Salesforce Certified Platform App Builder Transition Exam until March 30, 2018.".

As it is anyway going to expire by July 31, 2017, do I still have to give Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer Winter '17 Release Exam?

Please clarify..

Comment: I'm in the same scenario - I am going to do the release exam anyway as prep for the Platform App Builder and Platform Developer I exams that I need to take anyway. I suspect if you don't do the release exam there might be an issue with the Platform App Builder transition.

Comment: In addition to the answers, just take it. why risk it. If you do not take it you run the risk of your current credential expiring because you did not maintain it vs SF saying it is expired. It may put you in the category of needing to take the full exam again. It takes no time at all to complete

Comment: I am trying to register for "Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer Winter '17 Release Exam" but its not available now...

Answer (score 2):

For practical reasons, you will want to keep up with any release exams as that material will be covered in transition exams. In the past, you had to be current in your maintenance exams before you could take the transition exam.

With users now being given the opportunity to take the transition exam beyond the expiration of the renewal period for the certification, that may have changed. To get an "official answer", I recommend you ask this question on the Success Community in the [Salesforce U. Training & Certification Group](https://success.salesforce.com/0F9300000001oFf).